# Eclipse theme problem in Ubuntu Natty (11.04)

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu-11.04

[image: This is displayed when i press CTRL+Space]

When i use Eclipse in ubuntu Natty i am not able to read these tips. Please help me to solve these issues. I searched the web and got suggestions to install and use "Eclipse Color Themes" from http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/ still the problem exists. I have only tried java in Eclipse i hope that this problem exists for other languages Eclipse support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. @Xeon's answer helped me. In Eclipse  Window->Preferences->Java->Editor Then change the "Appearance color options" as needed.

[image: Eclipse Preference window]

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem - background and text on tooltips were black.

I've resolved this by going to Preferences->Apperance, Theme tab, Customize...,
On "Customize Theme" Dialog -> Colors tab.
Set "Tooltips:" colors as you like.

Currently I have white background and black text.